# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) ajax request

Tags: ajax, django

I have an ajax request, and in django view, i have following prints and outputs.

I have the error in this line and i cant figured it out why.

```
parsed_json = json.loads(request.body)
```

I trid to decode request body with utf8 but nothing has changed

AJAX CALL:

```
$("#add_user_button").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/user/',
        data:
            {
                'action': "addUser",
                'username': $('#id_username').val(),
                'password': $('#id_password').val(),
                'groups': $('#id_groups').val()
            }
        ,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        processData: false,
    });
}
```

DJANGO VIEW PRINTS:

```
print(request.POST.get("username"))
#print(request.encoding) #returns none
print("Request body is :")
print(request.body)
print(type(request.body))
```

OUTPUTS:

```
hello
Request body is :
b'username=hello&password=world&csrfmiddlewaretoken=&addUser=Add+User'
<class 'bytes'>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you analyse your request body you'll notice it is not JSON, to send JSON you have to encode it in your ajax request from your object.

```
$("#add_user_button").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/user/',
        data:
            JSON.stringify({ // <--here
                'action': "addUser",
                'username': $('#id_username').val(),
                'password': $('#id_password').val(),
                'groups': $('#id_groups').val()
            })
        ,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
}
```